# Saving/creating site from template resets all user columns

Tags: site-template

When I save a site as a template and create a new site based on that, all "Modified By", "Created By", etc. fields are reset from whoever originally created that content to my user name. Is there a way to avoid this?

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve this? I have an entire site of content that I want to move to a sub site on that same site. i.e.

from

1. Training 101 (site)

to

1. Training Home (site)

   1. 101 (sub site)
   2. 201 (sub site)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Server Publishing feature enabled then you can move the sub-site using the GUI. Go to Site Settings page. In Site Administration group, click on Content and Structure.

This will open an Explorer-look-alike web page. You can use this to move your sub-sites around like so many dominoes :)

The steps are;
1.  Go to Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Content and Structure of Parent site of the site to be moved.

1. Select the parent site of the sub site you want to move in the left navigation pane
2. Check the box next to the sub site that you want to move in the right pane, click the Actions drop-down and click Move…
3. Then select the destination of the sub site selected in the next dialog box, press OK button.

Comment: IS the answer satisfactory? If yes, can you mark it as answer please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There would be 2 option for you but both requires something like a tool that corrects the transferred data.

1. is to create a console application that compares Author, Editor, Created, and Modified fields and do the correction accordingly to the newly created subsite.

[Changing Created By (Author) and Modified By (Editor)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/21f65f64-54d8-450f-b261-3d2f4ae42bd9)

[Changing Created and Modified Dates](https://serverfault.com/questions/48190/change-the-created-and-last-modified-dates-in-sharepoint-moss-2007)

2 . Another Option is to just create a blank site and then transfer all the data from your original site to your new site. you can use [Copy Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy%28v=office.12%29.aspx) inside your console application or just directly work with the Server Object Model. [Client Object Model](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/28a43891-7505-4d34-b513-fdd66773c2a3) is also an option for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the site as a template, when I'm in a situation where I need to do this I just run the `Export-SPWeb` command in Powershell. If this is a list, not a document library, the `-includeversions` flag won't matter but you'll definitely want to utilize `-includeusersecurity` to preserve all of the Author/Editor fields (you'll need to add this flag during both the export and the import sequences).

```
Export-SPWeb http://website/web -path d:\yourfilename.cmp -includeusersecurity -verbose
Import-SPWeb http://newlocation/web -path d:\yourfilename.cmp -includeusersecurity -verbose
```

If this subsite has any size whatsoever, I strongly recommend creating a new directory for the .cmp file(s) to reside in. SharePoint by default will break up the export into ~30MB files. The `-verbose` flag is completely optional; Export-SPWeb also creates a log file that repeats the same information you'll see generated on-screen when you use `-verbose`. I like to use it as a way of making sure that the program is doing something. :)

Also bear in mind that adding on `-includeusersecurity` when you're exporting the website to an entirely different farm can significantly increase the length of the import, as the site will need to add each and every single user into the rootweb.